# How to extract sentences from a pandas dataframe which are given in a column as word-per-row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the most efficient way to loop over a large pandas dataframe in which sentences are given as word-per-row, and with punctuations in another column? For example:

```
d = {'col1': ['This', 'is', 'a', 'simple', 'sentence',
              'This', 'is', 'another', 'sentence',
              'This', 'is', 'the', 'third', 'sentence', 
              'Is', 'this', 'a', 'sentence', 'too'],
     'col2': ['', '', '', '', '!',
              '', '', '', '.',
              '', '', '', '', '...',
              '', '', '', '', '?']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
        col1 col2
0       This     
1         is     
2          a     
3     simple     
4   sentence    !
5       This     
6         is     
7    another     
8   sentence    .
9       This     
10        is     
11       the     
12     third     
13  sentence  ...
14        Is     
15      this     
16         a     
17  sentence     
18       too    ?
```

Then, I would like to extract and work on individual sentences, like this:

```
df[0:5]
       col1 col2
0      This     
1        is     
2         a     
3    simple     
4  sentence    !
```

or

```
df[14:19]
        col1 col2
14        Is     
15      this     
16         a     
17  sentence     
18       too    ?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would compute the position of each pair of sentence/word and make a *[MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-hierarchical)* :

```
grp = df["col2"].ne("").shift(fill_value=False).cumsum().add(1).rename("sentence")

out = (df.set_index(grp).assign(word=lambda x: x.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1))
           .set_index("word", append=True))
```

Output :

```
print(out)

                   col1 col2
sentence word               
1        1         This     
         2           is     
         3            a     
         4       simple     
         5     sentence    !
2        1         This     
         2           is     
         3      another     
         4     sentence    .
3        1         This     
         2           is     
         3          the     
         4        third     
         5     sentence  ...
4        1           Is     
         2         this     
         3            a     
         4     sentence     
         5          too    ?
          col1 col2
```

---

If you need the 2nd sentence as a DataFrame :

```
print(out.loc[2])

          col1 col2
word               
1         This     
2           is     
3      another     
4     sentence    .
```

---

Or, if you need it as a string :

```
s = " ".join(out.loc[2].agg("".join, axis=1))

print(s)

'This is another sentence.'
```

---

If you need the 3rd word for the 2nd sentence :

```
w = "".join(out.loc[pd.IndexSlice[2, 3], :].tolist())

print(w)

"another"
```

***Update :***

> A follow-up question: as `col2` actually contains a lot of garbage, can
> empty cell `.ne("")` be replaced by a list `.ne([".", "!", "?", "..."])` ?

```
m = df["col2"].isin([".", "!", "?", "..."])

grp = m.shift(fill_value=False).cumsum().add(1).rename("sentence")

out = (df.assign(col2= df["col2"].where(m)).set_index(grp)
         .assign(word=lambda x: x.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1))
         .set_index("word", append=True))
```

Comment: This looks great! Thanks [Timeless](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16120011/timeless). A follow-up question: as col2 actually contains a lot of garbage, can empty cell `.ne("")` be replaced by a list `.ne([".", "!", "?", "..."])`?

Comment: You're welcome ;) I think in that case, you can use `.isin([".", "!", "?", "..."])`. I made an update, can you check and see if it's good ?